# Firebird group by period

Tags: c#, linq, firebird

I am pulling some historical data from `Firebird` database as below:

```
Product_ID     Date     Price
1           2001-01-01  10  
1           2001-02-01  10
1           2001-03-01  15
1           2001-04-01  10
1           2001-05-01  20
1           2001-06-01  20
```

What I am trying to do is to extract the first for occurrence every price change.
Example of expected data set:

```
Product_ID     Date     Price
1           2001-01-01  10  
1           2001-03-01  15
1           2001-04-01  10
1           2001-05-01  20
```

I know that on `MSSQL` I could leverage `LAG` for that. Is it possible to do that with `Firebird`?

Comment: You can easily use a stored procedure on that. Go through all records (`FOR SELECT..... INTO...ORDER BY.....`) and when Price change just call `SUSPEND`.

Comment: Or you can try this (not tested - have no Firebird instance here): `SELECT Product_ID, MIN(Date), Price FROM xxx GROUP BY Product_ID, Date, Price`

Comment: That would retrieve only first instance of the same price, but it wouldn't retrieve the 2nd price change (10 on the 04-01)

Comment: Oh I see. So why not use stored procedure? Or - if you don't want to store a procedure - you can also use an EXECUTE BLOCK feature.

Comment: Firebird 3 supports [window functions, including LAG](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html#d0e5417)

Comment: can you make a helper table or a helper column for it and keep I up to date with triggers ?

Answer (score 0):

in MoreLinq there is a Lag extension method but it is supported only in Linq to Objects...

What you can do, if you are looking for a C# linq answer for that you can:

Basically order your data the correct way and then add a row index for while price (and product_id) is still the same. Then group by it and select the `min` date.

```
int groupingIndex = 0;
int previousPrice = 0;

var response = data
    .OrderBy(item => item.Product_ID)
    .ThenBy(item => item.Date)
    .Select(item =>
    {
        if (item.Price != previousPrice)
        {
            previousPrice = item.Price;
            groupingIndex++;
        }

        return new { Index = groupingIndex, Item = item };
    })
    .GroupBy(item => new { item.Index, item.Item.Product_ID, item.Item.Price } )
    .Select(group => new Record 
    { 
        Product_ID = group.Key.Product_ID, 
        Price = group.Key.Price, 
        Date = group.Min(item => item.Item.Date) 
    }).ToList();
```

And if you don't mind doing the operation in the C# and not the DB (and using a beta version of the MoreLinq) then:

```
int index = 0;

var result2 = data
    .OrderBy(item => item.Product_ID)
    .ThenBy(item => item.Date)
    .Lag(1, (current, previous) => new { Index = (current.Price == previous?.Price ? index : ++index), Item = current })
    .GroupBy(item => new { item.Index, item.Item.Product_ID, item.Item.Price })
    .Select(group => new Record { Product_ID = group.Key.Product_ID, Price = group.Key.Price, Date = group.Min(item => item.Item.Date) })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but be aware I didn't tested it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Test
RETURNS (
  Product_ID INTEGER,
  Date DATE,
  Price INTEGER
)
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE Last_Product_ID INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE Last_Date DATE;
DECLARE VARIABLE Last_Price INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR SELECT Product_ID, Date, Price
      FROM xxxx
      ORDER BY Product_ID, Date
      INTO Product_ID, Date, Price
  DO BEGIN
    IF ((:Last_Product_ID IS NULL) OR 
        (:Last_Date IS NULL) OR 
        (:Last_Price IS NULL) OR 
        (:Product_ID <> :Last_Product_ID) OR
        (:Price <> :Last_Price)) THEN
      SUSPEND;
    Last_Product_ID = :Product_ID;
    Last_Date = :Date;
    Last_Price = :Price;
  END;    
END;
```

Comment: or one can use EXECTE BLOCK instead of creating a persistent SP

Answer (score 0):

This is a little complicated but it works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Product_ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, DateTime.Parse("2001-01-01"),  10});  
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, DateTime.Parse("2001-02-01"),  10});  
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, DateTime.Parse("2001-03-01"),  15});  
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, DateTime.Parse("2001-04-01"),  10});  
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, DateTime.Parse("2001-05-01"),  20});  
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, DateTime.Parse("2001-06-01"),  20});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, DateTime.Parse("2001-01-01"), 10 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, DateTime.Parse("2001-02-01"), 10 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, DateTime.Parse("2001-03-01"), 15 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, DateTime.Parse("2001-04-01"), 10 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, DateTime.Parse("2001-05-01"), 20 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, DateTime.Parse("2001-06-01"), 20 });  

            dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date")).CopyToDataTable();
            List<DataRow> results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(g => g.Field<int>("Product_ID"))
                .Select(g1 => g1.Select((x, i) => new { row = x, dup = (i == 0) || ((i > 0) && (g1.Skip(i - 1).FirstOrDefault().Field<int>("Price") != g1.Skip(i).FirstOrDefault().Field<int>("Price"))) ? false : true })
                .Where(y => y.dup == false).Select(z => z.row)).SelectMany(m => m).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I take into account the Product_ID as well?